# How can I split this dataset by "|" but keep it in one column in Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, google-query-language

I'm trying to use `SPLIT()` here, but it only gets the first row:
Notice that the ranges are obtained dynamically, so that moving columns around won't lose the colum reference:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH("PO #",Sheet1!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+")&"5:"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH("PO #",Sheet1!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+"))&"|"&
INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH("PO #",Sheet2!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+")&"5:"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(5,MATCH("PO #",Sheet2!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+")))
```

This generates, which is not the end result:

[image]

The idea is to split it by the | and stack them up and avoid blanks.

Here's a sample of the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Fair enough, @player0! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing Thank you!

Comment: see the updated cleaner fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
INDIRECT("Orders!"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(6,MATCH("PO #",Orders!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+")&"6:"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(6,MATCH("PO #",Orders!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+"));
INDIRECT("Scenarios!"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(6,MATCH("PO #",Scenarios!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+")&"6:"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(6,MATCH("PO #",Scenarios!$5:$5,0)),"[A-Z]+"))}, "where Col1 is not null", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({
 INDIRECT(   "Orders!"&ADDRESS(6, MATCH("PO #",    Orders!5:5, ))&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2, MATCH("PO #",    Orders!5:5, ), 4), 2, ));
 INDIRECT("Scenarios!"&ADDRESS(6, MATCH("PO #", Scenarios!5:5, ))&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2, MATCH("PO #", Scenarios!5:5, ), 4), 2, ))}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", ))
```

[image]